# How to remove a modal page from NavigationStack in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, navigation, xamarin.forms

Here's an example for my **`Navigation`**:

```
LoginPage ( Login_Click  ) -> MainPage   | Block BackButton
MainPage  ( Logout_Click ) -> LoginPage  | Block going back to the MainPage
```

Currently I am using this code to show the `MainPage` after a successful login.

```
 await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new MainPage());
```

I **DON'T** want the users to go back by hitting the `PreviousButton(Android)` to return to the LoginPage.

Same story when logging out.

Is there a way to remove the LoginPage from the NavigationStack after a successful login (and remove the MainPage when logged out) ?

**NOTE:**

This is modal. 
I am not using a NavigationPage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for `PopToRootAsync`. So your user enters required info and they tap a login button, you perform your login verification and if success you set a new `MainPage` and then `PopToRootAsync` which pops all but the root Page off the navigation stack.

**Update**: Due to the way `PopToRootAsync` is done across the various platforms, you need to start from a `NavigationPage` but can remove it as your root page after your login process.

So in your Application constructor, instead of just creating your `LoginPage`, place it into a `NavigationPage` but **hide the navigation bar** so it does not effect your `LoginPage` screen layout:

```cs
public App()
{
    var navPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage());
    NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(navPage.CurrentPage, false);
    MainPage = navPage;
}
```

Then within your `LoginPage` you can set the `Application.Current.MainPage` to any `Page` class (does **not** have to be a `NavigationPage`) and then `PopToRootAsync` to get to it and totally remove your `LoginPage` from the navigation hierarchy.

```cs
public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
{
    public LoginPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        loginDone.Clicked += OnLoginClick;
    }
    async void OnLoginClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // If Login is complete/successful - set new root page
        if (YourLoginMethod()) {
            Application.Current.MainPage = new MainApplicationPage();
            // Pops all but the root Page off the navigation stack, with optional animation.
            await Navigation.PopToRootAsync(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: Tested this technique only on `iOS` and `Android`

Comment: That looks nice - thanks for your answer. Unfortunatley I get an `System.InvalidOperationException: PopToRootAsync is not supported globally on Android, please use a NavigationPage.` Why is that ?

Comment: @FeDe I updated my answer to handle the way `PopToRootAsync` is done across the various platforms

Comment: Thanks alot ! I will test this as soon as I get home but it already looks pretty nice. Android and iOS are the most important to me anyways :D

Comment: Thanks alot mate that helped me so much ! I had to make some little changes but the idea was great :D tanks :D

Comment: Too good, thank you. there are many solutions available but this is complete one for login authentication type apps

Answer (score 1):

Rather than pushing the new page onto the NavigationStack that you no longer want, just set the App.MainPage to the new page.