# What is the process to pop multiple modals in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, modal-dialog

I am creating a Xamarin.Forms mobile app that uses `Navigation.PushModalAsync()` for a Forgot Password page. After verifying the user, I am using a second `Navigation.PushModalAsync()` to load the page to actually reset the password.

The cancel button on the first page works fine with `Navigation.PopModalAsync()`, but I can't figure out how to remove the first Modal from the stack. When I attempt to use `Navigation.PopToRootAsync` or a kludgy `Navigation.RemovePage(Navigation.ModalStack.ElementAt(Navigation.ModalStack.Count -1))` (slightly modified from https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/346393/#Comment_346393), an exception is thrown:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'RemovePage is not supported globally on Android, please use a NavigationPage.'

or

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'PopToRootAsync is not supported globally on Android, please use a NavigationPage.'

My App.xaml.cs class has the following:

```
public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage());
        }
```

and I'm trying to return to the `LoginPage`, but I want to pop all of the modals from the stack so that the back button on an Android device doesn't load the modals again.

I also attempted the steps from [How to remove a modal page from NavigationStack in Xamarin.Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37398962/how-to-remove-a-modal-page-from-navigationstack-in-xamarin-forms), which makes my App.xaml.cs class:

```
var navPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage());
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(navPage.CurrentPage, false);
            MainPage = navPage;
```

but I still get the same errors.

The call in my second modal page is:

```
private async void CancelResetPasswordButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var answer = await DisplayAlert("Exit Password Reset?", "Are you sure you wish to exit the password reset process?", "Yes", "No");

            if (answer)
            {
                Navigation.RemovePage(Navigation.ModalStack.ElementAt(Navigation.ModalStack.Count - 1));
                await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
            }
        }
```

I have replaced what happens if Yes is selected with `await Navigation.PopToRootAsync();`, and the error appears again.

I'm sure it's probably something simple, but I'm not seeing the way to pop both modals to return to the `LoginPage` without the modals remaining in the stack.

Comment: Do you want to achieve the result like this gif? https://imgur.com/a/Wef9jba .If so, just add `await Navigation.PopToRootAsync();` in your `if (answer) {  }`

Comment: I did that, which returns `System.InvalidOperationException: 'PopToRootAsync is not supported globally on Android, please use a NavigationPage.'`

Comment: check this
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/125707/how-to-dismiss-multiple-pages-using-popmodalasync